# How do i send emails with attachments in react native (using my own SMTP server)?

Tags: email, react-native, smtp

Is there any way of sending an email, including Subject,To,From,Body and attachments to my own smtp server? I do not want to use [react-native-mail](https://github.com/esutton/react-native-mail) module, since it is a wrapper for native email apps, while I need to communicate with my own SMTP server.
Only "solution" I found was using [react-native-mailcore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mailcore), but it doesn't support attachments. Also, [react-native-email-smtp](https://github.com/Andrew-Lomakin/react-native-email-smtp), which supports attachments, is implemented only for Android. I need support for iOS too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up creating my own [react-native-smtp-mailer](https://github.com/angelos3lex/react-native-smtp-mailer) library for this:

Comment: it's a great library you have built, could it be possible to authenticate the user by Google Sign In and use the credentials to send SMTP email instead of providing email and password?

Comment: Maybe you want to use something like this then? https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail